# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer un archivo csv y modificar celdas despues de leer el archivo?

Tags: python, csv, email, python-3.7, xlrd

He estado trabajando sobre un script para enviar correos adjuntos. Ya que es algo pesado enviar 500 correos diarios y me he dado a la tarea de automatizarlo usando Python. El código analiza un excel en el cual exiten 6 columnas, entre las cuales está el nombre del archivo, la ruta del archivo, correo destino, estatus y nombre de la persona a la que le llegará el correo. El problema radica especialmente en que el script enviará todos los correos en que la columna de estatus tenga las palabras 'NO ENVIADO'. Hasta aquí todo va perfecto, el tema es que una vez que el codigo haya terminado de enviar el correo, en la columna estatus todas las celdas que tenían 'NO ENVIADO' cambien a'ENVIADO' para que en la siguiente ejecución del script no vuelva a enviar el correo.
Actualmente pensé en utilizar la librería XLRD, pero olvidé que solo lee. Pensé mejor en usar la librería csv, pero aquí es donde me topo con pared. No puedo hacer que funcione el script como lo había planeado. No sé como será mejor trabajar cada fila del archivo y por ende pasar los parámetros que necesita el código para poder enviar el correo y actualizar el csv.
Si alguien pudiera orientarme sobre como hacerlo, les estaré muy agradecido. Dejo el código para que puedan ver que es lo que hace actualmente.

```
import smtplib
import xlrd
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
 
# Iniciamos los parámetros del script
remitente = '' #correo del remitente
password  = '' #contraseña

#Declaramos las listas vacias que contendrán la información de cada una de las iteraciónes del recorrido de la hoja en excel
destinatarios = []
ruta = []
nombre_adjunto = []
nombre = []
estatus = []

#Abrimos la ruta de la ubicación del excel
filepath = 'C:\\Users\\emman\\Documents\\prueba\\Resultados Nuevo Leon.xlsx'

#abrimos el excel
openfile = xlrd.open_workbook(filepath)

#abrimos la hoja por el indice, osea la hoja 1, no importa que haya 10000 hojas, siempre abrirá la primera
sheet = openfile.sheet_by_index(0)

#hacemos un recorrido sobre la hoja en las columnas que contienen los datos para llenar las listas
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    nombre.append(sheet.cell_value(i, 1))
    destinatarios.append(sheet.cell_value(i, 2))
    nombre_adjunto.append(sheet.cell_value(i, 3))
    ruta.append(sheet.cell_value(i, 4))
    estatus.append(sheet.cell_value(i, 5))

#Creamos la variable Asunto del Correo 
asunto = 'Resultados de prueba'

#Creamos el texto que llevará del correo
cuerpo = 'Saludos, Se envían los resultados de la prueba solicitada.'

# Creamos la conexión con el servidor de correos, le asignamos los parametros del servidor SMTP con el Puerto, en este caso el 587
sesion_smtp = smtplib.SMTP('mail.miempresa.com', 587) #servidor de la empresa y el puerto smtp
     
# Ciframos la conexión
sesion_smtp.starttls()

# Iniciamos sesión en el servidor
sesion_smtp.login(remitente, password)

#creamos un arreglo para que recorra cada uno de los elementos de las listas para que posteriormente se creen los correos con un unico destinatario
for x in range(len(destinatarios)):

    #creamos la condicion para que se envien los correos pendientes y no los enviados o los que no hay resultado para enviar
    if estatus[x] == 'No enviado':      

        # Creamos el objeto mensaje
        mensaje = MIMEMultipart() 

        # Establecemos los atributos del mensaje
        mensaje['From'] = remitente
        mensaje['To'] = destinatarios[x]        
        mensaje['Subject'] = asunto
         
        # Agregamos el cuerpo del mensaje como objeto MIME de tipo texto
        mensaje.attach(MIMEText(cuerpo, 'plain'))

        # Abrimos el archivo que vamos a adjuntar
        archivo_adjunto = open(ruta[x], 'rb')
                 
        # Creamos un objeto MIME base
        adjunto_MIME = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')

        # Y le cargamos el archivo adjunto
        adjunto_MIME.set_payload((archivo_adjunto).read())
        # Codificamos el objeto en BASE64
        encoders.encode_base64(adjunto_MIME)        

        # Agregamos una cabecera al objeto
        adjunto_MIME.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % nombre_adjunto[x])

        # Y finalmente lo agregamos al mensaje
        mensaje.attach(adjunto_MIME)    

        # Convertimos el objeto mensaje a texto
        texto = mensaje.as_string()

        # Enviamos el mensaje
        sesion_smtp.sendmail(remitente, destinatarios[x], texto)    

        print('envio correcto a paciente: ', nombre[x], '|', destinatarios[x], '|', nombre_adjunto[x])

# Cerramos la conexión una vez enviados los correos
sesion_smtp.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando trabajas con un `csv` y en general cualquier archivos al que accedas secuencialmente, puedes modificar cualquier fila de forma arbitraria, pero, siempre en memoria, y para salvar este dato deberás nuevamente salvar el archivo completo (con el cambio).

Veamos un ejemplo bien sencillo:

Supongamos un `archivo.csv` como el siguiente:

```
"correo","mensaje","Status"
"alguien1@dominio.com","Hola, que tul?","ENVIADO"
"alguien2@dominio.com","Hola, que tul?","NO ENVIADO"
"alguien3@dominio.com","Hola, que tul?","NO ENVIADO"
"alguien4@dominio.com","Hola, que tul?","ENVIADO"
```

El proceso debe leer secuencialmente este archivo, verificar el `Status`, si corresponde, hacer el envío del mail, cambiar el `Status` a `ENVIADO` y una vez procesada cada fila, deberemos salvar completamente el archivo.

```
import csv

filas = []
with open('mails.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, quotechar='"', delimiter=',',
                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True)
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if row["Status"] == "NO ENVIADO":
          print(f'El mail a {row["correo"]} no se ha enviado.')
          # Aquí iría el proceso de envío que ya tienes
          # Al finalizar de forma existosa modificamos el Estatus
          row["Status"] = "ENVIADO"

        # Cada fila, modificada o no, la salvamos en una lista.
        filas.append(row)


# Salvamos nuevamente el archivo completo
fieldnames = ['correo', 'mensaje', 'Status']
with open('mails.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
  csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, quotechar='"', delimiter=',',
                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True,
                     fieldnames=fieldnames)

  csv_writer.writeheader()
  for row in filas:
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Este algoritmo tiene una eventual desventaja, en caso de archivos excesivamente grandes (no parece ser tu caso) el tenerlo en memoria puede no ser una buena idea.

Comment: Saludos, muchas gracias por contestar a mi duda. Me ha servido de mucho su respuesta ya que por fin pude visualizar lo que necesitaba. Pero hay 2 pequeñas dudas que tengo, al reescribir las filas se brinca una fila vacía y comienza escribir. Esto sucede cada vez que se ejecuta el script. La segunda es que en una celda va la ubicación del archivo, la cual viene de esta forma: C:\Users\emman\Documents\prueba\2020-06-10\2B2020061004.pdf
al guardarlo python a las diagonales les pone una diagonal extra. Perdón si abuso de su apoyo y en verdad me ha servido bastante su aporte. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Raro los de las barras  y lo de la fila ignorada, lo acabo de probar: https://repl.it/join/gsqxxqti-pmoracho y no me lo hace de eso, Revisa dónde podría estar el problema: lectura - tu proceso - escritura, probando primero leer el archivo y mostrar las filas por pantalla, luego con tu proceso y por último la escritura.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder. He revisado el codigo pero era necesario ponerlo en marcha. he hecho pruebas pero sigue sin funcionar y ya no sé porque suceda ya que incluso necesito poner un tipo fecha en una celda de esta forma 10-07-2020 ya que es el nombre de una carpeta, y obviamente la carpeta no puede ser 10/07/2020 y en el excel no puedo poner un dato 10-07-2020 a menos que sea tipo texto y conserve ese formato. No sé que más pueda hacer :(